# Elastic Search Handling Master/Slave Shutdown

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, configuration

I have a 3 node elastic search cluster deployed on AWS. One master node and 2 slave nodes. All my indexing and search queries are directed towards the master_IP:9200. My question is about handling a situation when the master node goes down. How can I know the new master node?

Below are the yaml files from my cluster.

Master:

```
#################################### Node #####################################

# Node names are generated dynamically on startup, so you're relieved
# from configuring them manually. You can tie this node to a specific name:
#
node.name: "Master_0"
path.data: "/mntebs/elasticsearch"
node.master: true
node.data: true

# Set the number of shards (splits) of an index (5 by default):
#
index.number_of_shards: 5

# Set the number of replicas (additional copies) of an index (1 by default):
#
index.number_of_replicas: 2
```

Slave_1:

```
#################################### Node #####################################

# Node names are generated dynamically on startup, so you're relieved
# from configuring them manually. You can tie this node to a specific name:
#
node.name: "Slave_0"
path.data: "/mntebs/elasticsearch"
node.master: false
node.data: true

# Set the number of shards (splits) of an index (5 by default):
#
index.number_of_shards: 5

# Set the number of replicas (additional copies) of an index (1 by default):
#
index.number_of_replicas: 1
```

Slave_2:

```
#################################### Node #####################################

# Node names are generated dynamically on startup, so you're relieved
# from configuring them manually. You can tie this node to a specific name:
#
node.name: "Slave_1"
path.data: "/mntebs/elasticsearch"
node.master: false
node.data: true

# Set the number of shards (splits) of an index (5 by default):
#
index.number_of_shards: 5

# Set the number of replicas (additional copies) of an index (1 by default):
#
index.number_of_replicas: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you only have 1 master eligible node in the cluster. If that node goes down, your cluster will go down and will become defunct; end of discussion. My suggestion to you would be to make all the 3 nodes master eligible, that is set `node.master` as well as `node.data` to `true` on all nodes. At a time only one of them will act as the master. If that node goes down, another node will be promoted as the master. This way your cluster will remain healthy (may go to `yellow` state though) even if two nodes are down. With this configuration, you need to direct your queries in a round robin fashion to all nodes. Many Elasticsearch clients support this feature out of the box.

Comment: **Don't suggest sending the requests to a single node** unless that node is a client node, please. That node will be overloaded (CPU, memory, disk).

Comment: I know. That is why I suggested using some client that usually round robins the requests.

Comment: I'm not seeing this message in your reply. Instead, I'm seeing "With this configuration, you need to direct your queries to one of the three nodes node and it that goes down, direct it to another node."

Answer (score 0):

There are some wrong things with your cluster:

- you are directing your requests to only one node. **Don't do that!** Round-robin the requests to all the nodes. Directing everything to a single node will overload that node and possibly bringing it down. And it's even more dangerous that your are this to your master node.
- make all your three nodes both `master` and `data`, not only one node
- if all three are master and data, use `minimum_master_nodes` setting to [avoid having a split-brain situation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_important_configuration_changes.html#_minimum_master_nodes). Any node can become a master and it doesn't matter which. Again, **don't send all the requests to a single node**, use [client nodes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/modules-node.html) and send the requests only to the client nodes or send the requests in a round-robin fashion to all the nodes in the cluster.

```
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
```

- have the same settings in all the nodes configuration files

`index.number_of_replicas: 2` on master, but `index.number_of_replicas: 1` on data nodes

Also, I suggest reading the documentation (which is very good btw) because you are lacking some basic things about Elasticsearch. Please, read the documentation.